# Validate columns against validationformula client object model while uploading documents

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject

Please see the below code where `List<order>` metadata contains values for my SharePoint columns/fields. I have to validate against Field.validationformula specified in SharePoint site. Can some one helps me to elaborate the provision how to do this validation.

```
   public bool UploadDocumentwithMetadata(string fileName, string filePath, string docLibraryName, bool overwrite,
        List<Order> metadata, string subfoldername)
    {

        bool uploadStatus = false;
        string fileurl;
        try
        {
            // Create the new file  
            if (subfoldername == "")
                fileurl = fileName;
            else
                fileurl = Path.Combine(docLibraryName + "/" + subfoldername, fileName);
            var newFile = new FileCreationInformation
            {
                Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath),
                Url = fileurl,
                Overwrite = overwrite
            };
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item = null;
            var docs = _site.Lists.GetByTitle(docLibraryName);
            if (docs != null)
            {
                StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
                uploadStatus = true;
                item = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields;field.Value.ToString();

                foreach (var order in metadata)
                {
                    Field fld = null;
                    foreach (var eachfield in docs.Fields)
                    {
                        if (eachfield.InternalName == order._InternalName)
                        {
                            fld = eachfield;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    string validationformula = fld.ValidationFormula;

                    item[order._InternalName] = order._Range;
                }

                /////
        ****/
        //if columns satisfies fld.ValidationFormula;
                    //then upload
        //else exist
        /***
        /////

            }

            return uploadStatus;

        }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I have exactly same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: same issue here with list validation